# Question about a definition $S_2 = \{x \in N : -x\in N\}$ from the book Mathematical Proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm wondering about the following from the book Mathematical Proofs

$$S_2 = \{x \in N : -x\in N\} = \emptyset$$

I'm not really sure what this is even saying I'm reading it as follows the set S2 has elements {X that are members of the natural numbers such that negative x are in the natural numbers}.
This statement seems nonsensical to me. What is this actually saying?

Another example from the book that seems absurd to me is the following.

$$\{x \in Z: |x| = -x\}$$

How can this ever be the case, that $|x| = -x$.

Thank you in advance for any help,

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Do you think that $S_2$ has elements?

Comment: I don't follow what it's even saying, like $\{x \in N: -x\in N\}$ seems ridiculous to me.  "Some x that is a natural number such that negative x is a natural number." This seems like some strange quantum effect where x can be simultaneously negative and positive. I Fail to see how this is even a logical statement to make.

Comment: This is just an example of a empty set, because, as you said, there is no natural number $x$ that, $-x$ is a natural number. Thus, there is no element in $S_2$. Another way to see that: assumed that $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$, suppose that there is an $x \in S_2$. So $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $-x \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $x + (-x) \in \mathbb{N}$, and We have $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. That's a contradiction. So, there is no elements in $S_2$.

Comment: Ok. I just gonna delete the comment, alright?

Comment: "This seems like some strange quantum effect where x can be simultaneously negative and positive."  It's nonsensical for that to ever be *true* but there is nothing at all illogical or nonsensical for that to be *false*.

Comment: Note if $x < 0$ then $|x|$ is .... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example of an empty set, because, as you said, there is no natural number $x$ that, $-x$ is a natural number. Thus, there is no element $S_2$. Another way to see that: assumed that $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$, suppose that there is a $x \in S_2$. So $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $-x \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $x + (-x) \in \mathbb{N}$, and, $0$ would be an element of $\mathbb{N}$. That's a contradiction. So, there is no elements in $S_2$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 2):

1. $S_2$ is the set of all natural numbers $x$ where $-x$ is also an natural number.

There are no such natural numbers at all[*].  So the set $S_2$ does not have any elements at all.

So $S_2 = \emptyset$.  $\emptyset$ is the set that has no elements at all.

It's *not* nonsensical to consider natural numbers have negatives that are natural numbers, any more than it is nonsensical to consider a rational square root of $2$.  The fact that there *aren't* any doesn't make it nonsense.  It just makes them non-existent.

2. How can $|x| = -x$?

Why shouldn't it be.

$|x|$ is always $0$ or positive.  So we just have to find an $x$ where $-x$ is $0$ or positive.

If $x = 0$ then $-x = -0 = 0$.

And if $x < 0$ then $-x > 0$.

SO what is $|0|$?  It is $0$.  ANd $|0| = 0 = -0$.  So that's one example.

And if $x < 0$ then $|x|=....$ well it equals the number that has the same *magnitude* as $x$ but in the positive rather than negative direction. In other words if $x < 0$ then $|x| = -x$.

In fact.... how was $|x|$ ever defined.  Most books *define* it as $|x| =\begin{cases}x& x\ge 0\\-x&  x< 0\end{cases}$.

So $\{x\in \mathbb Z: |x|= -x\} =\{0,-1,-2,-3,-4,......\}$.

But even if $|x| = -x$ was impossible that wouldn't be a problem.

We can have sets with no elements.  It's the empty set.

$\{$ even primes that are larger than $2\} =\emptyset$

$\{$ composite numbers that are prime $\} = \emptyset$

$\{$ square circles$\} = \emptyset$.

Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: thank you for this detailed explanation. It's very helpful.